# помогите найти синтаксическую ошибку switch case

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]ребят, помогите найти ошибку, редактор подсвечивает код в switch

```
const usersReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FOLLOW:
            let stateCopy = {
                ...state,
                users: state.users.map(u => {
                    if (u.id === action.userId) {
                        return { ...u, followed: true };
                    }
                    return u;
                }),
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: при наведении на подчеркиваемый код, обычно, показывается подсказка, что именно с ним не так

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Среда разработки, должна показать, что не хватает break перед default.

```js
const usersReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
      case FOLLOW:
          let stateCopy = {
              ...state,
              users: state.users.map(u => {
                  if (u.id === action.userId) {
                      return { ...u, followed: true };
                  }
                  return u;
              }),
          };
      break;
      default:
          return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Благодарю! Почему-то vs code не показывал, да и в документации не увидел этого. Невнимательно читал видимо.

Comment: @DmitryKrylov, потому что `break` - необязателен

Comment: я добавил break в код, все заработало, буквально через минут после сохранения break начал подсвечиваться, я убрал его и все стало ок, интересно почему так.

Comment: @DmitryKrylov Чудеса :)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том что case или должен остановиться (break нужен если ничего не возвращаем) или что-то вернуть (return если. нужно обновить state) у вас нет ни того ни друго-го.

Вы создали копию состояния, но вы не вернули его рудюсеру.

```
const usersReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FOLLOW: 
            let stateCopy = {
                ...state,
                users: state.users.map(u => {
                    if (u.id === action.userId) {
                        return { ...u, followed: true };
                    }
                    return u;
                }),
            };
            return stateCopy;

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Или более лаконичный вариант:

```
  const usersReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case FOLLOW: {
        return {
          ...state,
          users: state.users.map(u => u.id === action.userId ?  { ...u, followed: true } : u),
        };
      }
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
```